# MySql FULLTEXT search relevance adjustment

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, match, relevance

Looking through other posts on here I have not been able to find my specific requirement.

Here is my example

I have some products in a database with the following titles.
And this is the order I would like them to appear in if the user searches for "mushroom pie"

1.mushroom pie
2.Mushroom Pie
3.Pie Mushroom
4.Mushroom soup
5.Pork Pie
6.Mushroom & Wild Mushroom Soup

I have added full text to the "title" field in my products database... But unfortunately it is not doing what I would like .

```
SELECT products.title ,products.normalisedCode
FROM products
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+mushroom +pie' )
```

This puts "Mushroom & Wild Mushroom Soup" at the top of my results... I imagine this is because "mushroom" appears twice in the title.

Also when I add in another "like" statement

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8;
SELECT products.title ,products.normalisedCode
FROM products
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+mushroom +pie' ) 
OR products.normalisedCode LIKE CONCAT('%', normaliseNumString('mushroom'), '%')
```

This completely messes up the sorting... I have tried using the boolean match mode ... but this only brings back products with both key words in its title... I need it to bring back any product with either word in the title but putting those with both words in the correct order at the top of my results.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT (MATCH(title) AGAINST ('mushroom Pie')) as Relevance,
products.title ,products.normalisedCode

FROM products 
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+mushroom +Pie' )

ORDER BY Relevance DESC
```